# Продажа приложения в стране, которая не входит в список разрешенных

Tags: android, google-play

Дело в том, что моя страна не входит в список разрешенных стран для регистрации разработчика и при регистрации разработчика я обошел этот пункт, зарегистрировав страну США. Потом об этом даже позабыл.

Но сейчас предстало передо мной задача, продавать виртуальные монеты и само приложение. Моя страна опять же не входит в список стран где разрешено продавать приложение и все такое.

**Вопрос**: Как мне добиться этого находясь у себя в стране?

**PS**. Переехать не вариант.

Comment: А что за страна, если не секрет?

Comment: Да не секрет. Кыргызстан. Обидно то, что в нашей стране более развита сфера разработки в отличие от других Средне Азиатских стран которые вошли в список Гугла(

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу два варианта, более реалистичный второй:

1. Иметь человека в США, который будет снимать деньги за какой-то откат.
2. Монетизировать приложения через рекламу, используя независимый сервис типа [Appodeal](https://www.appodeal.com/home/ru/).

Comment: А какой бы вы выбрали: Appodeal или AdMob?

Comment: @TITAN, не той, не той. У меня нет приложений с рекламой. Но хочу взять Appodeal, потому что там удобнее вывод средств. Намного удобнее, чем AdMob...